# Ruby return syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, return

The code below returns `true` if `@var` is non-`nil`.

```
class MyClass
    def a_simple_method
        not @var.nil?
    end
end
```

When I use the keyword `return` like this:

```
class MyClass
    def a_simple_method
        return not @var.nil?
    end
end
```

it returns a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '('
        return not @var.nil?
                       ^
```

What did I understand wrong about `return`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tells you to use `()`

```
class MyClass
    def a_simple_method
        return not(@var.nil?)
    end
end
```

Comment: I thought I tried that before, but I added a space in front of `(`. Old habits which made it fail with another syntax error.. +1

Answer (score 1):

You need parenthesis for `return` or for `not`

```
class MyClass

    def a_simple_method
        return(not @var.nil?)
    end
end

class MyAnotherClass

    def a_simple_method
        return not(@var.nil?)
    end
end

MyClass.new.a_simple_method
MyAnotherClass.new.a_simple_method
```

### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=ruby-return-syntax.rb&run=true)